# Pass variable submit name in post

Tags: variables, post, submit

I'm a new entry in this fantastic site. I need to pass with post method a name of a submit that is a variable. For example:

```
<input type="submit" name="<?php echo $row["idTable"]; ?>">
```

And next in my php I will need to:

```
$_POST['submit_name'];
```

How can I do?

Comment: In sorry the Real code of the submit is:

Comment: <input type="submit" name="<?php echo $row["idTabella"]; ?>"

Comment: Please help me.